# How far can I cut back this hedge?

Tags: pruning, shrubs, hedge

I have this hedge (lavender star flower -- Grewia occidentalis):

[[image: The Hedge]]
[image: The hedge]
[image: Flowers]

It is growing in a very dark corridor between my house and the fence.  It does pretty well there, but I need to paint the fence.  How far can I cut back this species and have it grow back?

Comment: The real question is how long do you want to wait before it looks nice again?  One season or ???